# Method referenced in XState machine is not callable within class but works when declared as global

Tags: typescript, xstate

Why cannot I reference a method declared within the same class as XState service? If I move the method outside of the class, it works fine.

```
export class LoaderMachine {
    service = interpret(createMachine<LoaderContext, LoaderEvent, LoaderState>(
        {
        .....
        }, {
            actions: {
                fetch() {
                    this.fetchDataInsideClass(); // not callable
                    fetchData(); // global declaration works
                },
                restart() {
                    console.log('Recovering from error')
                    service.send('RESTART');
                },
                finished(context, event) {
                    console.log('Done');
                }
            }
        }));

    async fetchDataInsideClass() {
        try {
            console.log('Started');
            service.send('SUCCESS');
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Failed with ${err}`);
            service.send('ERROR');
        }
    }
}

async function fetchData() {
    try {
        console.log('Started');
        service.send('SUCCESS');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Failed with ${err}`);
        service.send('ERROR');
    }
}
```

Results in a compilation error:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.
Not all constituents of type 'AssignActionObject<LoaderContext, LoaderEvent> | ActionObject<LoaderContext, LoaderEvent> | ActionFunction<...>' are callable.     
Type 'AssignActionObject<LoaderContext, LoaderEvent>' has no call signatures
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your sample code is that `actions.fetch` is a function declaration that will set its execution context (the `this` binding) in the runtime depending on how it's called. For more information, check out the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

A quick fix is to declare `actions.fetch` (and all the other action implementations) as an arrow function that will be bound to the instance of `LoaderMachine` class.

```js
actions: {
    fetch: () => {
      this.fetchDataInsideClass(); // not callable
      fetchData(); // global declaration works
    },
    restart: () => {
      console.log("Recovering from error");
      service.send("RESTART");
    },
    finished: (context, event) => {
      console.log("Done");
    },
  },
```